# В том числе

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли обособлять запятыми "в том числе"?
"Должны быть указаны в качестве обязательных в том числе следующие условия"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном примере - нет, т.к. оборот имеет значение "также", а не вводит присоединительную конструкцию, как это с ним обычно бывает. ))